# Magento 2 Replace a default JS

Tags: magento2, javascript, overrides

here i am replacing configurable.js with my own module. but its not working, and the default one is loading. do i need to initialize it as well ?
here is the code

**path : app/code/ABC/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
map: {
    "*": {
        'attributesLoader': 'ABC_Module/js/configurable',
        'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': 'ABC_Module/js/configurable'
    }
}
};
```

my configurable.js is

**path : app/code/ABC/Module/view/frontend/web/js**

i am just calling console.log in create function. to know which one is working.

static-contents deplyed, cache folders removed.

Answer (score 0):

You do it not right way
Try mixins way like this

```
config: {
      mixins: {
          'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
              'ABC_Module/js/configurable': true

              }
         }
};
```

This tell magento to replace configurable.js by your script

Comment: Very incomplete... You have to write your _configurable.js_  the proper way. see http://alanstorm.com/the-curious-case-of-magento-2-mixins/ or google ;)